# Форматирование флешки FAT32 в NTFS

Tags: ntfs, usb

Т.к. нужно было залить файл размером 10гб, то мне не подошла файловая система FAT32, т.к. на неё нельзя кидать файлы свыше 4гб. Форматнул флешку в NTFS. Файл стал заливаться, но фильм доходил до середины и дальше не шёл, писало файл повреждён, получается опять принимает нормально толкьо первые 4гб. Что делать в такой ситуации? Может кто сталкивался? Весь инет перерыл, что только не пробовал.

Comment: Простите, а откуда уверенность что файл цел, или флешка не отформатировалась в нужном формате? На другом файле (а лучше 2-3) размером более 4 Гб пробовали, появляется ли эта ошибка снова?

Comment: я б добавил, что нужно попробовать забить флешку под завязку небольшими файлами или сделать скандиск с проверкой целостности.

Comment: CHKDSK выполнял, всё норм там писалась файловая система NTFS. Также забивал влешку файлами меньше 4гб - всё ок. А файл этот я с компа запускал без проблем, он нормальный

Comment: То есть, это ещё и не компом проигрывается? А чем?